# Fabric: unable to get environment variables within virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, fabric

I've a Django project which runs in virtual environment. 
Also there is line `export ENV=staging` in `.bashrc` file.
And in settings I try to read this using `os.getenv('ENV')` but it returns None.

settings_staging.py

```
...
ENV = os.getenv('ENV')
...
```

.bashrc

```
...
export ENV=staging
...
```

Error

```
[dev.gipi] out:   File "/home/ubuntu/projects/deeyoon/settings/settings.py", line 61, in <module>
[dev.gipi] out:     raise Exception('Environment variable ENV is requried!')
[dev.gipi] out: Exception: Environment variable ENV is requried!
```

What may cause the problem or what is goin wrong with?

Sultan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common problem is that .bashrc file is never executed. Type `env` and check if ENV variable is there.

Comment: I remembered that fabric uses login shell and `.bashrc` isn't executed in login shells but `.bash_profile` works just fine

Answer (score 10):

There is one more case when fabric ignores .bashrc.
Often .bashrc contains following line:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

Comment it out.

Comment: Who would have thought it was a problem with the .bashrc!?
Cheers!